# Pollard's $\rho$ algorithm and quadratic sieve

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, computational-complexity

I am wondering why is quadratic sieve better than Pollard's $\rho$ for integer of $10^4-10^{10}$ digits? The running time of quadratic sieve is $e^{(1+o(1))\sqrt{\ln n\ln \ln n}}$, but the Pollard's $\rho$ only has $O(n^{1/4}$. Isn't this much quicker than the running time of quadratic sieve?

Comment: The quadratic sieve method is best for large numbers (lets say, $80$ digits or more). For very small numbers, pollard-rho is more efficient.

Comment: Why Is it the case?

Comment: The pollard-rho method works well, if the smallest prime factor has upto, lets say, $15$ digits. The quadratic sieve method does not depend on the structure of the factorization, only on the input size. It is routine to factor $80$ digit-numbers with a fast implementation. If you invest a day, you can factor $100-110$ digt-numbers.

Comment: By the way, the elliptic curve method works well if the smallest prime factor has $30$ or fewer digits.

Comment: As others have alluded to, your first statement is false in general.  Among other things, Rho's expected time is based on the size of the smallest factor, while QS on the size of the input.  QS can find multiple factors at once, while Rho finds one at a time.  For numbers under 30 or so digits, Rho, P-1, P+1, and ECM will be faster than QS given comparable implementations (many QS impls don't even work at small sizes).  For larger numbers, typically one uses Rho,P+/-1,ECM to quickly remove small factors, then go to QS/NFS.